# Adding a new node before the first child in dom tree

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

This is probably one of those easiest things to deal with but for some reason not working for me. I'm trying to add a new node after the root in dom tree.
Here's the original string:

```
<div class="discussionThread dt"><div class="dt_subject">2011 IS HERE!</div></div>
```

I'm trying to add a new node which is in the form of a string before . The final version should look like:

```
<div class="discussionThread dt"><div class="test">Test Val</div><div class="dt_subject">2011 IS HERE!</div></div>
```

As you can see, the new **Test Val** is being added immediately after the root div class. I've used few methods to place the node at the right place but its getting appended at the end.

Here's a sample which I referred from one of the earlier posts:

```
String newNode = "<div class="test">test</div>";
SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
Document newNodeDocument = reader.read(new StringReader(newNode));
Document originalDoc = new SAXReader().read(new StringReader(content));
Element root = originalDoc.getRootElement();
Element givenNode = originalDoc.getRootElement(); 
givenNode.add(newNodeDocument.getRootElement());
```

This is resulting the node getting added at the end. I tried using insertBefore(), but didn't work out.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? It's hard to tell what you're doing wrong without looking at your code.

Comment: Just added a sample code for your reference.

Comment: what library are you using? dom4j?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why create a new `Document` or a new root `Element`? I think the shortest way is using `Branch#content`:

> Returns the content nodes of this
>   branch as a backed List so that
>   the content of this branch may be
>   modified directly using the interface.
>   The List is backed by the Branch so
>   that changes to the list are reflected
>   in the branch and vice versa.

You just have to create the new Element and to add it to the root element through the `List` provided by `content` method (passing it the position index), this is my main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException {

    SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
    String xml = "<div class=\"discussionThread dt\"><div class=\"dt_subject\">2011 IS HERE!</div></div>";
    Document document = reader.read(new StringReader(xml));

    DefaultElement newElement = new DefaultElement("div");
    newElement.addAttribute("class", "test");
    newElement.add(new DefaultText("Test Val"));

    List content = document.getRootElement().content();
    if (content != null ) {
        content.add(0, newElement);
    }

    System.out.println(document.asXML());
}
```

which prints out the following xml:

```
<div class="discussionThread dt"><div class="test">Test Val</div><div class="dt_subject">2011 IS HERE!</div></div>
```

In addition, you should also consider the use of xslt when you have to transform xml.

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution. It's very close to what I was looking for. It does add the new element at the intended position. The problem here is you are explicitly creating a new Element and setting the necessary attribute and text value. In my case, the data I need to insert is passed as a string parameter to my program. The value can be a single div or a multiple divs bundled together. For e.g. <div class="test2">Test Val1</div><div class="test2">Test Val2</div> . I was thinking if its possible to add the entire string content as is after the root element

Comment: @Shamik If you want to add the whole xml fragment received as a string, you just need to parse it as xml, but the string must be well formed xml. Unfortunately your example string doesn't have a unique root element, but two sibling nodes... and a document can have only one root node.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling [`Element#add(Entity)`](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/Element.html#add%28org.dom4j.Entity%29). From the Javadocs:

> Adds the given `Entity` to this element. If the given node already has a parent defined then an `IllegalAddException` will be thrown.

So the new node you're adding will be added as a *child* of the node you're adding it to. You cannot add another node after the root node you have, because a document can have only one root node.

What you can do is create a new root node, then add the old root node and the new node as children of this new root node. Then set the root node of the document to the new root node.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a new Document with the value you want, then append the other nodes to it?